# Adding properties to Okta UserProfile - Java API version 0.0.4

Tags: java, okta, okta-api

Java API version 0.0.4 for Okta UserProfile class in the `com.okta.sdk.models.users` package allows `email`, `secondEmail`, `firstName`, `lastName`, and `mobilePhone` to be saved to the user profile. However, I'm trying to store additional properties to the profile. Is there a way to do this with **this** API version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't supported in 0.0.4.  You will need up update the latest version: https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java